# How do I prevent an enumerate item at the second level from being split between two pages?

Tags: page-breaking, enumitem, amsthm, forest

[image]

looks bad. How can I prevent this? I tried `midpenalty`, but it didn't work. The code is presented below.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*,
  labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em,
  leftmargin=*,midpenalty=100000}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 25}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show the following simple arguments are valid by translating into QL and
  using trees.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Everyone is rational; hence Socrates is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall xRx$
        [$\neg Rs$,ass
        [$Rs$,ass
        [*,ass]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item No one loves Angharad; hence Caradoc doesn’t love Angharad.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x\neg Lxa$
        [$\neg\neg Lca\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lca$,ass
        [$\neg Lca$,ass
        [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item No philosopher speaks Welsh; Jones is a philosopher; hence Jones
    does not speak Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Fx\supset\neg Gx)$
        [$Fj$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Gj\checkmark$,ass
        [$Gj$,ass
        [$Fj\supset\neg Gj$,ass
        [$\neg Fj$ [*,ass]]
        [$\neg Gj$ [*,ass]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item Jones doesn’t speak Welsh; hence not everyone speaks Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg Gj$
        [$\neg\neg\forall xGx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall xGx$,ass
        [$Gj$,ass [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item Socrates is rational; hence someone is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$Rs$
        [$\neg\exists xRx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x\neg Rx$,ass
        [$\neg Rs$,ass [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item Some philosophers speak Welsh; all Welsh speakers sing well;
    hence some philosophers sing well.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark$
        [$\forall x(Gx\supset Sx)$,ass
        [$\neg\exists x(Fx\wedge Sx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x\neg(Fx\wedge Sx)$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$Ga$,ass
        [$\neg Ga$ [*,ass]]
        [$Sa$
        [$\neg Ga$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Sa$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item All electrons are leptons; all leptons have half-integral spin; hence
    all electrons have half-integral spin.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Ex\supset Lx)$
        [$\forall x(Lx\supset Hx)$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Ea$,ass
        [$\neg Ha$,ass
        [$\neg Ea$ [*,ass]]
        [$La$
        [$\neg La$ [*,ass]] [$Ha$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item All logicians are philosophers; all philosophers are rational people;
    no rational person is a flat-earther; hence no logician is a flat-earther.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Lx\supset Fx)$
        [$\forall x(Fx\supset Rx)$,ass
        [$\forall x(Rx\supset\neg Ex)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark$,ass
        [$La$,ass
        [$Ea$,ass
        [$\neg La$ [*,ass]] [$Fa$
        [$\neg Fa$ [*,ass]] [$Ra$
        [$\neg Ra$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Ea$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item If Jones is a bad philosopher, then some Welsh speaker is irrational;
    but every Welsh speaker is rational; hence Jones is not a bad philosopher.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$Bj\supset\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark$
        [$\forall x(Gx\supset Rx)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Bj\checkmark$,ass
        [$Bj$,ass
        [$\neg Bj$ [*,ass]] [$\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark$
        [$Gj$,ass
        [$\neg Rj$,ass
        [$\neg Gj$ [*,ass]] [$Rj$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrth gwrs mae Jones yn siarad Gymraeg! Pwy arall? Smith yw'r un ddi-Gymraeg....

Comment: @JohnKormylo A monarchy?!!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Er... really? But even if that were true, he wasn't in a monarchy. Maybe he wanted to be. Maybe he caused others to be. But he wasn't. [I'm not sure that it is possible to establish historical facts in this case given the competing accounts of his life, the conflicting reasons for which they were written and the melding of those accounts into other things, all combined with the fragmentation and repeated rearrangements and re-collating....]

Comment: @JohnKormylo Ate what? It isn't as though they were translating Socrates. There's nothing to translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this kind of layout is suitable for your requirements. It allows a page break before the solution, but not within it. The layout is also slightly more compact.

[image: adjusted trees]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*, labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em, leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south
    }
  },
  default preamble={
    prooftree,
    for root={baseline},
    for tree={%
      if n children=1{for children={ass}}{},
      math content
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 25}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Show the following simple arguments are valid by translating into QL and
  using trees.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Everyone is rational; hence Socrates is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\forall xRx
        [\neg Rs
        [Rs
        [*]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item No one loves Angharad; hence Caradoc doesn’t love Angharad.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x\neg Lxa
        [\neg\neg Lca\checkmark
        [Lca
        [\neg Lca
        [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item No philosopher speaks Welsh; Jones is a philosopher; hence Jones
    does not speak Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Fx\supset\neg Gx)
        [Fj
        [\neg\neg Gj\checkmark
        [Gj
        [Fj\supset\neg Gj
        [\neg Fj [*]]
        [\neg Gj [*]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item Jones doesn’t speak Welsh; hence not everyone speaks Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\neg Gj
        [\neg\neg\forall xGx\checkmark
        [\forall xGx
        [Gj [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item Socrates is rational; hence someone is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [Rs
        [\neg\exists xRx\checkmark
        [\forall x\neg Rx
        [\neg Rs [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item Some philosophers speak Welsh; all Welsh speakers sing well;
    hence some philosophers sing well.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark
        [\forall x(Gx\supset Sx)
        [\neg\exists x(Fx\wedge Sx)\checkmark
        [\forall x\neg(Fx\wedge Sx)
        [Fa
        [Ga
        [\neg Ga [*]]
        [Sa
        [\neg Ga [*]] [\neg Sa [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item All electrons are leptons; all leptons have half-integral spin; hence
    all electrons have half-integral spin.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Ex\supset Lx)
        [\forall x(Lx\supset Hx)
        [\neg\forall x(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark
        [\exists x\neg(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark
        [Ea
        [\neg Ha
        [\neg Ea [*]]
        [La
        [\neg La [*]] [Ha [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item All logicians are philosophers; all philosophers are rational people;
    no rational person is a flat-earther; hence no logician is a flat-earther.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Lx\supset Fx)
        [\forall x(Fx\supset Rx)
        [\forall x(Rx\supset\neg Ex)
        [\neg\neg\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark
        [\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark
        [La
        [Ea
        [\neg La [*]] [Fa
        [\neg Fa [*]] [Ra
        [\neg Ra [*]] [\neg Ea [*]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
    \item If Jones is a bad philosopher, then some Welsh speaker is irrational;
    but every Welsh speaker is rational; hence Jones is not a bad philosopher.
    \begin{sol}
      \begin{forest}
        [Bj\supset\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark
        [\forall x(Gx\supset Rx)
        [\neg\neg Bj\checkmark
        [Bj
        [\neg Bj [*]] [\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark
        [Gj
        [\neg Rj
        [\neg Gj [*]] [Rj [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

If you prefer the tree to appear below the word 'Solution', you might integrate that into the tree. This automatically ensures that the tree is kept with the word.

For example, you might set the following preamble in `\forestset{}`:

```
  default preamble={
    prooftree,
    for root={ass},
    for tree={%
      if n children=1{for children={ass}}{},
      math content
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      !r.append''=!c,
      !r.delay={
        content=\text{\textbf{Solution.}}
      }
    },
    before packing={
      !rl.append=!r1,
    },
    before drawing tree={
      !r.x/.min={x()}{descendants},
    }
  },
```

This is a little tricky. It involves making a copy of the root node, replacing the contents of the root with the the title 'Solution.' and then appending the remainder of the original tree as a sub-tree of the copied root node. The title is then vertically aligned to the left side of the tree.

The first page looks like this:

[image: solutions with trickery]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*, labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em, leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
    }
  },
  default preamble={
    prooftree,
    for root={ass},
    for tree={%
      if n children=1{for children={ass}}{},
      math content
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      !r.append''=!c,
      !r.delay={
        content=\text{\textbf{Solution.}}
      }
    },
    before packing={
      !rl.append=!r1,
    },
    before drawing tree={
      !r.x/.min={x()}{descendants},
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 25}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Show the following simple arguments are valid by translating into QL and using trees.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Everyone is rational; hence Socrates is rational.

      \begin{forest}
        [\forall xRx
        [\neg Rs
        [Rs
        [*]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item No one loves Angharad; hence Caradoc doesn’t love Angharad.

      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x\neg Lxa
        [\neg\neg Lca\checkmark
        [Lca
        [\neg Lca
        [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item No philosopher speaks Welsh; Jones is a philosopher; hence Jones does not speak Welsh.

      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Fx\supset\neg Gx)
        [Fj
        [\neg\neg Gj\checkmark
        [Gj
        [Fj\supset\neg Gj
        [\neg Fj [*]]
        [\neg Gj [*]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item Jones doesn’t speak Welsh; hence not everyone speaks Welsh.

      \begin{forest}
        [\neg Gj
        [\neg\neg\forall xGx\checkmark
        [\forall xGx
        [Gj [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item Socrates is rational; hence someone is rational.

      \begin{forest}
        [Rs
        [\neg\exists xRx\checkmark
        [\forall x\neg Rx
        [\neg Rs [*]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item Some philosophers speak Welsh; all Welsh speakers sing well; hence some philosophers sing well.

      \begin{forest}
        [\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark
        [\forall x(Gx\supset Sx)
        [\neg\exists x(Fx\wedge Sx)\checkmark
        [\forall x\neg(Fx\wedge Sx)
        [Fa
        [Ga
        [\neg Ga [*]]
        [Sa
        [\neg Ga [*]] [\neg Sa [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item All electrons are leptons; all leptons have half-integral spin; hence all electrons have half-integral spin.

      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Ex\supset Lx)
        [\forall x(Lx\supset Hx)
        [\neg\forall x(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark
        [\exists x\neg(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark
        [Ea
        [\neg Ha
        [\neg Ea [*]]
        [La
        [\neg La [*]] [Ha [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item All logicians are philosophers; all philosophers are rational people; no rational person is a flat-earther; hence no logician is a flat-earther.

      \begin{forest}
        [\forall x(Lx\supset Fx)
        [\forall x(Fx\supset Rx)
        [\forall x(Rx\supset\neg Ex)
        [\neg\neg\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark
        [\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark
        [La
        [Ea
        [\neg La [*]] [Fa
        [\neg Fa [*]] [Ra
        [\neg Ra [*]] [\neg Ea [*]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \item If Jones is a bad philosopher, then some Welsh speaker is irrational; but every Welsh speaker is rational; hence Jones is not a bad philosopher.

      \begin{forest}
        [Bj\supset\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark
        [\forall x(Gx\supset Rx)
        [\neg\neg Bj\checkmark
        [Bj
        [\neg Bj [*]] [\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark
        [Gj
        [\neg Rj
        [\neg Gj [*]] [Rj [*]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd rather see it broken above the item. It still looks suboptimal to me.

Comment: Oh. I see. I did it this way because it looked odd to me having 'Solution.' and then a line break. In truth, what I would really do if you want the line break is put 'Solution.' within the tree. That way, you know it cannot get broken away from the rest.

Comment: @crocket Please see edit.

Comment: By the way, I don't care if the tree appears beside Solution or below it. I just want to stop second-level enumerate items from being split in the middle. Your solution kind of works, but it looks overly complex. Can it not be made simple and elegant? @cfr

Comment: I think I misunderstood. I've never found a good way to stop items breaking in that sense. One option is not to use a list at all but instead use sectional divisions, for example. This is a misuse, I admit, but you can leverage LaTeX's reluctance to break after a sectional heading. Why not use John's solution if you want no break at all? My first solution isn't complex it just sets the baseline for the tree. But it doesn't do what you want, so that's hardly a selling point.

Comment: If I have to choose between the two, I'd rather sacrifice a bit of layout to retain simplicity. By the way, does `\pagebreak` stretch enumerate?

Answer (score 1):

You can always put an entire item into a `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{...}`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\Alph*,align=left,leftmargin=*,
  labelsep=1.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.,labelindent=1em,labelsep=1.5em,
  leftmargin=*,midpenalty=100000}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  ass/.append style={
    before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
    no edge
  },
  prooftree/.style={
    for tree={
      child anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Exercises 25}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show the following simple arguments are valid by translating into QL and
  using trees.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Everyone is rational; hence Socrates is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall xRx$
        [$\neg Rs$,ass
        [$Rs$,ass
        [*,ass]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item No one loves Angharad; hence Caradoc doesn’t love Angharad.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x\neg Lxa$
        [$\neg\neg Lca\checkmark$,ass
        [$Lca$,ass
        [$\neg Lca$,ass
        [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item No philosopher speaks Welsh; Jones is a philosopher; hence Jones
    does not speak Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Fx\supset\neg Gx)$
        [$Fj$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Gj\checkmark$,ass
        [$Gj$,ass
        [$Fj\supset\neg Gj$,ass
        [$\neg Fj$ [*,ass]]
        [$\neg Gj$ [*,ass]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{Jones doesn’t speak Welsh; hence not everyone speaks Welsh.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\neg Gj$
        [$\neg\neg\forall xGx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall xGx$,ass
        [$Gj$,ass [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}}
  \item Socrates is rational; hence someone is rational.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$Rs$
        [$\neg\exists xRx\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x\neg Rx$,ass
        [$\neg Rs$,ass [*,ass]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item Some philosophers speak Welsh; all Welsh speakers sing well;
    hence some philosophers sing well.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\exists x(Fx\wedge Gx)\checkmark$
        [$\forall x(Gx\supset Sx)$,ass
        [$\neg\exists x(Fx\wedge Sx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\forall x\neg(Fx\wedge Sx)$,ass
        [$Fa$,ass
        [$Ga$,ass
        [$\neg Ga$ [*,ass]]
        [$Sa$
        [$\neg Ga$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Sa$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item All electrons are leptons; all leptons have half-integral spin; hence
    all electrons have half-integral spin.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Ex\supset Lx)$
        [$\forall x(Lx\supset Hx)$,ass
        [$\neg\forall x(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x\neg(Ex\supset Hx)\checkmark$,ass
        [$Ea$,ass
        [$\neg Ha$,ass
        [$\neg Ea$ [*,ass]]
        [$La$
        [$\neg La$ [*,ass]] [$Ha$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item All logicians are philosophers; all philosophers are rational people;
    no rational person is a flat-earther; hence no logician is a flat-earther.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$\forall x(Lx\supset Fx)$
        [$\forall x(Fx\supset Rx)$,ass
        [$\forall x(Rx\supset\neg Ex)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark$,ass
        [$\exists x(Lx\wedge Ex)\checkmark$,ass
        [$La$,ass
        [$Ea$,ass
        [$\neg La$ [*,ass]] [$Fa$
        [$\neg Fa$ [*,ass]] [$Ra$
        [$\neg Ra$ [*,ass]] [$\neg Ea$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \item If Jones is a bad philosopher, then some Welsh speaker is irrational;
    but every Welsh speaker is rational; hence Jones is not a bad philosopher.
    \begin{sol}
      \leavevmode

      \begin{forest}
        prooftree
        [$Bj\supset\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark$
        [$\forall x(Gx\supset Rx)$,ass
        [$\neg\neg Bj\checkmark$,ass
        [$Bj$,ass
        [$\neg Bj$ [*,ass]] [$\exists x(Gx\wedge\neg Rx)\checkmark$
        [$Gj$,ass
        [$\neg Rj$,ass
        [$\neg Gj$ [*,ass]] [$Rj$ [*,ass]]]]]]]]]
      \end{forest}
    \end{sol}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You know, you could have just stuck a `\rule{1pt}{.95\textheight)` in front of one `\item`.